# Android 4.4: Bluetooth Low Energy; Connect without scanning for a BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth

my app shall connect to a Bluetooth LE device. Usually you perform a device scan using `mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);`. The callback provides you information about available devices.

If you want to connect to a dedicated device, you do something like

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
```

and then

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

To me it looks like the only thing you need to connect to a BLE device, is to know the BLE address and then connect to it with the above two steps. So if I know a BLE address already (e.g. it is written on the label of the BLE device) I don’t need to perform a BLE scan.

But what I have encountered is, that if I have a BLE device which I have never found through a BLE scan before, it is not possible to connect to it directly in using its BLE address. I have to find it through a scan at least one time with my android phone. Afterwards I never need a scan again and I can connect to the BLE device just by using its BLE address.

Is it supposed to be like this or did I oversee something?

Thanks a lot,
Stefan

Comment: Could it be [pairing and/or bonding](https://piratecomm.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/ble-pairing-vs-bonding/) is required before connecting?

Comment: As far as I understood BLE, this is not necessary. Also if I do perform a scan, I do nothing for pairing or bonding and it works. The problem is to connect to a device directly without ever doing a BLE scan.

Answer (score 6):

The answer from Hoa Do is not really correct.

Due to some horrible design flaws in Android's BLE API there is no way to tell it if you mean the given address is a Public Address or a Random Address. (You can read more about different address types at https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/43670/how-to-distinguish-between-random-and-public-gap-addresses/). The getRemoteDevice method should take an additional parameter "random address/public address" but it doesn't. Without the correct address type, the Bluetooth controller cannot connect to the device.

Android's BLE stack has some internal heuristics to "guess" if the address is public or random, but unfortunately that differs between Android versions and also if you use autoConnect=true or false. However if you have bonded the device (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()) then it will store in its internal DB whether the given address is public or random. If the peripheral you want to connect to uses a random resolvable address it can handle that as well if you use bonding. Therefore I strongly suggest to use bonding.

If you don't use bonding you will need to scan before you connect to the device, since when you start a scan and a device is detected, Android's BLE stack will temporarily (until next restart of Bluetooth) remember the address type for an address. If you don't scan the device before connecting, it will still try to connect, but there is a possibility it tries to connect with the wrong address type and hence fail.

Answer (score 4):

The device address is merely a unique identifier for the bluetooth device, it doesn't contain the information for connection. The scan is necessary to retrieve the information within the broadcast signal from the bluetooth device so that a connection can be made. Once the scan is done, the information is saved somewhere on the device and bound to the device address.

I think if you try to retrieve the value for the bluetooth address it will return null until after it has been scanned once.

Comment: Do you have a source confirming this?

Comment: [Source](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/Baseband.aspx) 
It doesn't say this specifically and while I'm no expert at bluetooth protocols, my deduction is that while the device address can be used to identify the device, it doesn't specify what channel to communicate on. The protocol specifies an inquiry channel for slave and master devices to learn about each other and provide further instructions for connection. Once that information is retrieved, then the master can save that information and perform a connection directly next time as it already has the instructions.

Comment: Note that this is also true for BLE devices which are not bonded. meaning once a scan has completed and services discovery was made once android will cache the services and calling  BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address); will result in a connection within less than 1 sec.

Answer (score -1):

Many years have passed since this was first asked and I was able to make the following work. My device does not have a random address so if you know this about your device then the following should work fine.

```
// perform scan, get device and store address somewhere 
// like in shared preferences
String bleAddress = bluetoothDevice.getAddress();
this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("BLE_ADDRESS",bleAddress .apply();


// next time no need to scan, just get the remote device
// from the bluetoothAdapter and connect.
String address = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("BLE_ADDRESS",null);
if (address != null) {
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(ble_address)
    device.connectGatt(context, false, this, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
}
```