# How to auto connect without searching for bluetooth low energy devices in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a flutter ble application project for Android devices. In this project, after devices are scanned and connected to a device in the list created, I want to connect to the same device automatically without scanning again. Can you help me how to do this?

Comment: It is not possible to connect to a device without scanning for it. This is not possible using the Android NDK and therefore not possible using flutter.

Comment: Is it possible to save the scanned device to the database and connect again?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886725/android-4-4-bluetooth-low-energy-connect-without-scanning-for-a-ble-device

Comment: You need to clarify if you need help with building the Flutter UI, or help with the lower layer Bluetooth stuff. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43482099/556495 for the latter.

Comment: Do you guys mean it's not possible for BLE? Because it definitely is possible in Bluetooth Classic, I already did it.