# Is it require to have location permission and Location service enabled to connect to BLE device via MAC ID

Tags: android, rx-java2, bluetooth-gatt, rxandroidble

i have been using rxAndroidBLE lib on my android app to scan and connect to BLE devices. i know that location permission and location services needs to be enabled to scan nearby BLE devices but if i just want to connect to nearby BLE devices with it's macID(that i already know) is it still require to ask user to provide location permission and enable location services?

i have tried to connect to BLE device with it's MACID without granting Location permission or enabling Location services still i'm able to connect to BLE device on my device(Samsung S20) but some of our users are not able to connect to their BLE device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not required, but please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57099437/556495 why you can't always connect using only the Bluetooth Device Address.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Emil. so basically it's recommended to always ask user to allow Location permission and Location services while using app which need to connect to any nearby BLE devices.

Comment: Yes if the device is not bonded you should scan for it, and hence require location. If the device is already bonded you don't need to scan.