# Does Bluetooth need to be on for BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Assuming I already know the macAddress of the device I'm connecting to, so I don't need to scan devices before, can I directly connect to the device even if the bluetooth is off?

Comment: I don't think so. I assume you're trying to write an app that connects to a known peripheral. In that case, you're right to say you don't need to scan, but you still need Bluetooth to be enabled in your Android device. You should be able to programmatically check if Bluetooth is enabled or not. If it isn't, you won't be able to enable it directly, but you should be able to request the user to enable it for you.

Comment: Regarding connecting without scanning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886725/android-4-4-bluetooth-low-energy-connect-without-scanning-for-a-ble-device

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need Bluetooth to be enabled for all Bluetooth and BLE operations. BLE is a subset of Bluetooth (which also includes Bluetooth classic) so without Bluetooth being enabled you wont be able to scan, connect, or exchange data.

Useful links:

- [Android BLE overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview)
- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/)

Comment: In my Ionic App I am able to connect by macaddress (without scanning devices before) even if bluetooth is off. I am using this library https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central. Reproduced also with a simple BLE scanner app available in the Google Play, like BLE scanner: Bluetooth on is required to scan devices, but ones are discovered it is possibile to connect to them also after turning off the blueetooth @youssif-saeed

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to BLE devices when Bluetooth is OFF

The first thing you do when you work on bluetooth is getting the BluetoothAdapter by using

```
val adpater = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
```

or

```
val adapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter()
```

These methods will return null if Bluetooth is OFF, if Bluetooth is ON instance of Adapter is returned.

You use this adapter to get scanner to scan for devices.

When you turn off the Bluetooth, the variable still holds an object of adapter. This adapter still works even when the Bluetooth is Off.